# Is there anyone here familiar with this zend debugger error found in apache's error log?

Tags: php, apache, windows-xp, zend-debugger

```
[Zend Debugger] Cannot receive start command
...
[Zend Debugger] Cannot send message
```

I googled and found there are others also having this problem ([here](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=1471) and [this one on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/85702/zend-debugger-cannot-receive-start-command)), but unluckily no fix yet.

```
PHP 5.2.8 (cli) (built: Dec  8 2008 19:31:23)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2008 Zend Technologies
```

Is there an official fix for this yet?

Comment: Could you describe your debugging setup a bit closer? (e.g. php.ini part configuring zend debugger, QUERY_STRING environment variable, etc.)

Comment: The setup has no difference , I'm debugging the drupal, so can't reproduce easily without giving all the code,you know...

Comment: @wamp: The error message indicates that the debugger on the server can not 'talk' to your development environment (Eclipse?, some editor?, ...). There are *plenty of possible reasons* for this, depending on how your debugging environment is set up. So my question was aimed at getting some more details that would allow us to speculate on possible reasons. Those Details would be e.g. your Zend Debugger server configuration settings in php.ini, your client side setup (what do you use for debugging - Eclipse? If so, how did you configure debugging there), QUERY_STRING env variable on client, etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this issue can't be reproduced easily. So it only helps if you met exactly the same problem.

Comment: @wamp: This gets somewhat ridiculous - how should I know if I 'met exactly the same problem', if you do not provide the information necessary to judge if my encounters where the same problem? (As stated, the errors you posted are *generic* errors that can have plenty of causes - depending on your environment)

Comment: These messages mean Zend Debugger is unable to communicate with Studio, for one reason or another. Unfortunately, it's hard to know why without having more details...

Comment: @wamp: Could you find any clue so far?

Answer (score 1):

Well, like Henrik already said, this is hard to diagnose with no information about your setup at all. Also, if Roman (the rbzend from the thread you linked at the Zend Forum) has no solution at hand, it is likely really an incompatibility you have to live with for now.

If this is something that was fixed, your best bet would be to download the latest version of Zend Debugger from the Zend website. Then go through installation again as explained in the [Sticky Note Setting Up Zend Debugger in the Zend Forum](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=962).

If reinstalling Zend Debugger doesn't help and you do have a valid support license with Zend, you might want to open a ticket with Zend Support. I have opened a few tickets with them myself and found them very helpful. So far, they solved all issues I had with Zend Debugger and Zend Studio. If you don't have a valid license, you can still register for the Zend Forum and ask there.

As a random idea, you might get the Debugger working by disabling IPv6 in Zend Studio/Eclipse by starting it with `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`. I remember I had an issue with Zend Debugger because of that once. But of course it might be completely unrelated to your troubles - it's really just a straw.

Finally, if you don't mind, you can still change to [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) instead.

Comment: @Gordon, my issue only happens with some pages definitely, doesn't happen with some others,also definitely.

Comment: Not sometimes, for page A,it always works, but for page B,it always doesn't work.

Comment: @wamp Does the page work without Zend Debugger enabled? Does the page send any weird headers or destroy Cookies or something? It's impossible to tell what's wrong without code. Like I said, Zend Support is your best bet here.

Comment: @Gordon, sure, of course,that's the weiredest thing I've met,no clue,and even impossible to trace...

Comment: @wamp sorry, cannot help you with that beyond what I have alredy suggested then.